# C# How to setup presets with a context menu using windows forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, list, contextmenu

I am trying to do something new in my learning of C#. I recently posted a similar question to setting up and populating a context menu directly. Now that I have that done, I find myself stuck getting the execution I need.

I am creating a quick access list that is user defined. It is simply a name and IP Address.

I am populating the list from an xml docmuent and adding to the context menu by:

```
ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(string name, image, eventargs onClick)
```

Where I am stuck is trying to figure out how to tell the click event what IP to use. I know in a method argument I could pass the IP address by adding another argument to the function such as:

```
doSomething("Hello World");

  void doSomething(cmd)
{
 messageBox.Show(cmd);
}
```

How do get my variable menu choice to indicate the right IP address to the name? I assume if I can get the right IP used then I can use the same method to utilize the password as well. 
   so my code looks like:

```
 private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         ...
          foreach(xml node in xml doc)
           {
            Room r = new Room();
            r.Name =xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
            r.IP = xNode.SelectSingleNode("IP").InnerText;
            r.passwrd=xNode.SelectSingleNode("Pass").InnerText;
            locations.add(r);
            presetsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(r.Name, null, disp);
            }    
        }
 void disp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(r.Name's IP address);
            MessageBox.Show(r.Name's password);
        }
```

I am not against using another means of doing this. This was just what I could find that appeared to be the most simple. I just want to make sure it remains simple and the context menu/list is populated from an xml document.

Comment: I apologize to all reading this. I didn't realize that I didn't include the foreach statement and the fact that this menu is being populated from an xml document. I apologize for this error as I think it makes quite a difference on how this situation is approached.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one slightly ugly way to do it, by using the Tag property of the DropDownItem.

Using your code:

```
var item = new ToolStripMenuItem(string name, image, eventargs onClick);
item.Tag = "your.ip.address";
ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item)
```

Then,

```
private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
            Room r = new Room();
            r.Name ="Name"; 
            r.IP = item.Tag.ToString();
            r.passwrd="Password";

            presetsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(r.Name, null, disp);

        }
```

**A different possible solution:**

I'm not sure how your classes are laid out,  but you might want to have a separate lookup class that stores a mapping of Name->IP.  Then do something like this,

```
var item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
IPLookuper.GetIP(item.Text);//.Text corresponds to name in  "ToolStripMenuItem(string name,..."
```

A lookup is easy enough, just throw the items in a Dictionary.

**3rd edit**

Because you know the type that calls the disp method,  you could think of it like this,

```
 void disp(ToolStripMenuItem sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     var ip = sender.Tag.ToString();
     //Lookup the name/password/whatever based on the IP.
     MessageBox.Show(r.Name's IP address);
     MessageBox.Show(r.Name's password);


     }
```

the sender object is just whatever class fired off the event,  so you can cast it if you know what type it is.

Since your actual code uses 'object sender',  you'll just have to cast it yourself.

```
 void disp(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     var item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
     var ip = item.Tag.ToString();
     //Lookup the name/password/whatever based on the IP.
     MessageBox.Show(r.Name's IP address);
     MessageBox.Show(r.Name's password);

     }
```

Comment: I can see why you said this would be a slightly ugly way to do it. I would have to create global variables at run time. at this point I definitely see where this can get messy.

I get the feeling that to achieve this more cleanly I might have to change my approach. If that is the case what would be a better approach?

Comment: I think you have given me the answer to what I need. I think using the Dictionary is going to be the way to go. But I fear my understanding is still short of being able to connect the dot. 

I think where I need my last bit of help is during the event. When the event is executed I dont know how to get the right reference. Since the name and everything about the menu Item is dynamically created I don't know how to call its attributes. How can I tell the 'eventargs' ('disp()') to get the '.Name' or '.tag' of the specific menu item clicked so I can reference the dictionary?